# What does "|" between arguments in cat command do?

Tags: command-line, pipe, cat

I understand what the "cat" command does.
I.e.

```
cat file1 file2 > file3
```

Will put the contents of file1 and file2 in file3. (If I am not mistaken)

But what exactly does:

```
cat file1 | file2 > file3
```

do?

I don't have a UNIX machine to test this on, and I can't google " | ", hence my question.

Comment: Nothing... unless `file2` is an executable in your path you'll get _"command not found: file2"_ and an empty `file3`.

Comment: cat has nothing to do with that... unless `file2` is an executable it throws an error saying not found. Remove this question or get an online linux shell and test.

Comment: @don_crissti And if file2 is an executable?

Comment: @Pkarls if `file2` is executable it will get the output of `cat file1` as it's `stdin` and then anything `file2` prints to `stdout` will be put in `file3`

Comment: After closer investigation, I think that it might be, thanks!

Comment: @Pkarls: Now please don't ask, what if `file3` is a command.

Comment: @Thushi Not going to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pipeline. It will redirect the standard output of the first command into the standard input of the second command.

```
cat file1 | grep example
```

For example, the above command will catenate the requested file into grep's stdin.

The command you posted would fail.

```
cat file1 | file2 > file3
```

file2 isn't an executable and thus the operation would stop there.